# Git post-receive hook hanging

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have a git post-receive hook which builds a Go program and runs it.
The problem is that I'm getting all the output from the Go program and the `git push` "never finishes" the execution, getting stucked there.

I'm looking a way to run the Go program without hanging the push command.

My post-receive file:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
    branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
    if [ "production" == "$branch" -o "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    ...

        go build

        exec ./webservice

        echo 'Pushed!'
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest to put the go (and the exec ?) in backgroung with
`(go build ; exec ./webservice )&`

You will not be informed if there is a problem in your go program by git, so you will need a log

Maybe a better solution will be to automatically kill the go program if it is too long with `timeout`.

Comment: I tried your solution and I'm getting the webservice output in my git. And it is still hanging. I also tried to redirect the output to a file, but git still hangs.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
nohup ./webservice > output.txt 2>&1 &
```

This way, I can log the `stdout` and `stderr` to a file and avoid hanging the git `post-receive` hook.